# Signal R Javascript client - Is the connection being re-used?

Tags: javascript, signalr.client

I have an MVC5 application using signal R. In the code i have created a connection to signalR. Some pages consist of the layout which contains client methods and views which also create client methods (added using "Define method on client (without the generated proxy, or when adding after calling the start method)" in the asp.net documentation.
Code from Layout:

```
var myHub = $.connection.signalRHub;
myHub.client.clientfunction = function () {
    functionToCall();
        };
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Code from view:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();

var myHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('signalRHub');
myHubProxy.on('anotherFunction', function (trnID) {
        anotherFunctionToCall();
    });

connection.start();
});
```

When switching between pages in the application it looks as though many connections are being created. Each time a page is loaded and different views selected, a new connect?transport=... line is created in the Chrome Developer Tools, Network log. The event stream for each of these is the same. Is this expected behaviour?

Update 1:
After switching pages several times the application stops responding